# Directives with isolated scope: how to avoid $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.foo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Starting off from the "How to create directives that communicate" from angularJS guide, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive,

I am trying to use that layout to make a navigable form.

The problem is that the directives isolate their namespace, so when I want to reference the main scope for inserting data from the inputs, I need to do this:

```
<div id="showfoo">Foo = {{foo}}</div>

<form-tabs>
  <form-tab>
    <input ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.foo" />
  </form-tab>
  <form-tab>
    <input ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.foo" />
  </form-tab>
  <form-tab>
    <input ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.foo" />
  </form-tab>
</form-tabs>
```

This is understandable, since a child scope is created for each transclude and each isolate scope, so in total nesting of 4 is created.

The question is, how to avoid this? Ideally I'd want to make an `<input ng-model="foo">`, and have it update the `div#showfoo`

See http://plnkr.co/edit/jgD7a6W53518qpyLNUcx?p=preview for the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - Try to avoid using ng-model on a non object item: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Second - You can either try with a service (looks less nice), or use the new pattern http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/ where you can just continue to enjoy scope inheritance.

Comment: As far as I understood this far by skimming the articles linked, this still requires one to specify which variables I want to bind - something I want to avoid in order to create a reusable directive. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Problem was not using the dot in ng-model. Also had to create the object in the controller in order to bleed through, even if totally empty.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't following.
The idea in the 2nd article is to have both binding and not isolate the scope, which wasn't possible up to 1.4. 
The first one was because I saw something that looked off and I wanted to warn you :)

Comment: Seems like the transcluded scopes actually prototypically inherit from the main scope that I want to bind to - pointed out by one of the many articales i skimmed through trying to solve this. Problem was the "dotting", changing the instance of the scope variable doesn't work as one would intuistically expect (however it makes sense if you think about it in a functional way - you are changing the instance, not modifying it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use controllerAs syntax on directives in the same way that you can with with regular controllers.

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Answer (score 0):

Using isolated scope is not always needed, but if you really have to, you can also send your `foo` object like you send the `title`.

```
  scope: {
    title: '@',
    foo: '='
  }
```

And in html:

```
Foo = {{foo.x}}

<my-tabs>
<my-pane title="Hello"  foo="foo">
  <input ng-model="foo.x"></input>
  <h4>Hello</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</my-pane>
```

You also have to initialize the `foo` object in order to pass its reference, in this specific example it's on the `$rootScope`.
[You can check it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWlOwnGGahAvwmoIQr5B?p=preview)

Comment: The whole point would be able to make a general, reusable directive, not having to modify it for every use case (the bound variables would vary)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra how is this general? `$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.foo` - you still have to know the name `foo`. It's your choice anyway :) This just another option.

Comment: I don't really follow :)

You obviously want to know what to bind to. Anyways, seems like the problem was the "no-dot" problem in ng-model, or better defined the fact that I was binding to a string rather than an object attribute in the transcluded markup.